Failed to boot Windows 10 after resizing volume
I have a late 2013 iMac dual booting windows bootcamp and iOS 11 with the rEFInd boot manager. I ran out of space in the boot camp partition, so I got gparted live on an USB to resize the volume. Since there is no more to the right (succeeding) the volume, the volume was shifted left. Now when booted up, both Bootcamp (bios) or EFI windows reports that bootmgr is missing.
I did a little bit of googling, and I thought heat the guide on refind docs might help, since I thought it was a issue with rEFind initially, since I have no problem doing such resizing operations on other systems. I created a Windows recovery USB using the "create recovery drive" command on a working normal Windows 10 system (not dual boot).
While I run the commands in order, I realized that the EFI partition is missing, and the only partition with FAT32 is the recovery one. I expect the output to be similar to this, but the volume seems to be missing entirely.
In any case, I attempted the method anyway, knowing that it might not work due to the absence of the EFI partition.
I ran the following in order while booting into the recovery usb and into the command prompt:
diskpart
The [picture][4] show the output of the diskpart command.
sel vol 2
> Volume 2 is the selected volume
3. assign letter =S:
> DiskPart sucessfuly assigned the drive letters or mount point.
4. exit
> Leaving DiskPart...

Now the current directory is X:\windows\system32 Then I continue to follow the refind docs, but got a error.
cd /d R:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\


The system can not find the drive specified.

I dig around more, and this article at the "diskpart" section suggests that I should use the same letter as the number I assigned to the FAT32 partition, so then ran the following command instead, basically changing the drive letter from R to S:
cd /d S:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

The current directory then changed to S:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\ Then I continue witht he guide, and I ran the following:
bootrec /fixboot

And got this error:
> Access is denied.

I stop at this point, since the rEFInd docs said it should just work afterwards. I know I goofed up with me relocating every single sector, and now nothing is in the right place. Other than that, is it a problem with MBR, EFI bootloader, BCD, a combination of them, or anything in between? I have zero clue.
One thing to note is that running diskutil list on my intact iOS partition show that the EFI volume does exist, but windows doesn't show it, or that I just couldn't find it.
What should I do?

I believe iOS 11 cannot be installed on an Intel 2013 iMac. Can you explain how you did this? You mention "windows bootcamp". Does this mean you used the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10 on your Mac? If you did, then Windows 10 would have been installed to UEFI boot. If you upgraded to Windows 10 from an older Windows, then this may not be true. For example, Windows 7 is normally installed to BIOS boot on a 2013 iMac.
